# How to maintain CakePHP sessions across multiple AJAX requests?

Tags: ajax, facebook, session, cakephp

**Question in a Nutshell**

I need to be able to maintain sessions across multiple AJAX requests in CakePHP. Currently, the sessions are lost in each AJAX request.

**Background**

I'm trying to convert a Facebook app's server-side (PHP-SDK) authentication to utilize client-side (JS-SDK) authentication instead. The app is built with CakePHP and makes use of the Auth component.

The user flow I am trying to achieve is as follows:

1. User enters app.
2. User clicks a "Login with Facebook" button and authorizes the app via the Facebook auth dialog. I obtain the FB access token and pass it to the server via an AJAX call.
3. Using the access token, the server determines whether the current user is a new or existing user and performs the necessary registration and/or login processes.
4. The user may be still on the same page, and may trigger other AJAX functionality which require user authentication (on both CakePHP and Facebook).
5. The server should read the session previously started via the AJAX call, and if the user is authenticated, perform the desired operation.

The issue I have is with step 5 of the above flow. In particular, `$this->Auth->loggedIn()` returns false in the second (and subsequent) AJAX calls, and I get a HTTP 403 error. From my observation, it seems like the sessions are not being maintained as `$this->Session->id()` returns different values for each AJAX call.

I have looked through many similar questions on StackOverflow, but have not found a working answer. Some I have viewed:

- [CakePHP Session component - mysterious disappearance of session data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518517/cakephp-session-component-mysterious-disappearance-of-session-data)
- [ajax request ends CakePHP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028263/ajax-request-ends-cakephp-session)
- [CakePHP 403 on AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507568/cakephp-403-on-ajax-request)

Here is my session configuration:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_secure' => false,
        'session.referer_check' => false,
        'session.cookie_httponly' => false
    )
));
```

I have also tried `Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium')` as well to no avail.

If it helps, here's the code I have for the AJAX login:

```
public function ajax_login() {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $data = array();

    $accessToken = $this->request->data['access_token'];

    $response = null;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . FACEBOOK_SECURITY_APP_ID . '&client_secret=' . FACEBOOK_SECURITY_SECRET . '&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=' . $accessToken);
    parse_str(curl_exec($ch), $response);
    curl_close($ch);

    $newAccessToken = $response['access_token'];

    FB::setAccessToken($newAccessToken);

    try {
        $facebookUser = FB::api('/me', 'GET', array('fields' => 'id,username,first_name,last_name,email'));

        //Log in user
        //NOTE:: FB::getUser() returns 0 for some reason
        if ($facebookUser) {
            $isLoggedIn = $this->Auth->loggedIn();

            //Log out app user if Facebook IDs do not match
            if ($isLoggedIn) {
                $appUser = $this->User->find('first', array(
                    'conditions' => array('id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
                    'recursive' => -1
                ));

                if ($appUser && $appUser['User']['facebook_id'] != $facebookUser['id']) {
                    $this->Auth->logout();
                }
            }

            //Log in Facebook user
            $user = $this->User->findOrCreate($facebookUser);

            if (!$isLoggedIn) {
                $this->Auth->login($user['User']);
            }
        }
        //Log out app user if Facebook authentication fails
        else if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            $this->Auth->logout();  
        }
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $data['error'] = $e->getResult();
    }

    $data['status'] = $this->Auth->loggedIn() ? 1 : 0;

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**Other Points**

- I am using CakePHP 2.4.3 and Nick's CakePHP Facebook plugin (https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin).
- `$this->User->findOrCreate()` is a custom method that adds determines if the supplied Facebook user is an existing user, inserts records to the database if it isn't, and returns the found or created user.
- Ideally, I should avoid having the re-authenticate the user (on the server side) for each AJAX request. This would be akin to the workaround presented in ["An active access token must be used" (Dec 2012) && The proper way to set up Facebooks PHP-SDK for Ajax calls to get the user-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635991/an-active-access-token-must-be-used-dec-2012-the-proper-way-to-set-up-fac).
- I also want to avoid passing session IDs in each AJAX request to maintain the session. It raises too many security concerns.

**Bonus**

Will be great if anyone can additionally figure why FB::getUser() in the above code returns 0 although FB::api('/me') works.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Nick's Facebook Plugin. 
The plugin will auto login the user(create a user record if no account) when you connect Facebook. Sounds like what you are trying to do is already handled by the Plugin.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yup, I've been using the plugin for a while as well. The thing though is the plugin works off server-side authentication. This means if I use `FB.login()` from Facebook's JS SDK for authorization, the server gets nothing.

Comment: So on step 2. User clicks a "Login with Facebook" button, after successful Facebook authorization, the page should refresh and redirect to the login area. You should not bother step 3,4 and 5?

Step 3,4 and 5 should be handled in Nick's Facebook Plugin callbacks? (beforeFacebookSave,beforeFacebookLogin and afterFacebookLogin).

Comment: The idea is I want to avoid the refresh completely; which is unfortunately where the problem comes in. With the refresh, everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks, now the question is clear to me. :).  I have tried to duplicate your scenario on my environment. I am using PHP session though. The session ID seems consistent to me. So I am thinking if this is something related to Database session.